# c++ templates call specific constructor for specific type of class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I’m trying to make generic binary tree in c++ using templates.
So for example the type of value in Node class could be string, int or double.

I create my tree from the string and in in method I extract e.g single number from string and call constructor for Node.

Node class in header file without rest of the methods:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
Node(const string value){
    this->value = value;
    this->leftChild = nullptr;
    this->rightChild = nullptr;
};
private:
T value;
Node *parent;
Node *rightChild;
Node *leftChild;
};
```

So what I’m asking is how to define different constructor for specific type of Node class so e.g it would be possible to do:

```
Node<int> node(„2”);
```

and define and call constructor like:

```
Node(const string value){
    this->value = stoi(value);
    this->leftChild = nullptr;
    this->rightChild = nullptr;
};
```

Before I was trying to has just one constructor but overload = operator:

```
void operator=(int &n,string &s){
n = stoi(s);
};
```

But when it’s defined outside of class, compiler say "overloaded 'operator=' must be a non-static member function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to learn about *member initializer lists*: C++ initializes object directly. So you’d have a ctor like this:

```
Node::Node(std::string const& value)
    : value(value) // this line will need adjustment; see below
    , leftChild(nullptr)
    , rightChild(nullptr) {
}
```

For a generic data structure you’d most likely actually adjust the ctor argument type to match the value type. It is unusual that a generic data structure deals with type conversions. However, for the discussion below I’ll assume you want to stick to `std::string`, e.g., because the values are read from a text file.

If you need to convert between types you’ll want to use a generic type converter. These come in two flavors:

1. an existing function template like [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)
2. use a specific customization point

Both approaches have their place and it may be reasonable to even combine them. What they have in common is that the generic code uses identical syntax and the type-specific handling is done elsewhere.

### Using `boost::lexical_cast`

The idea of `boost::lexical_cast` is to convert the argument to a character sequence, parse the result using a stream to produce the destination type, and yield the result. The actual implementation is heavily optimised to avoid costly operations for common conversions, e.g., the conversiin from `std::string` to `int` iis effectively doing the same as `stoi()`.

It would be used like

```
Node::Node(std::string const& value)
    : value(boost::lexical_cast<T>(value))
    , leftChild(nullptr)
    , rightChild(nullptr) {
}
```

### Using a Customization Point

Another approach is to define a specific *customization point*, i.e., a generic interface which can be customized by users of the data structure. The advantage of this approach is that there is a bit more flexibility, e.g., to do suitable conversions based on how the data structure is used. Using a suitable default could avoid the drawback that the customization point has to be defined by every user.

Assuming the function used for the conversion is called `my_convert` it could be used like that (there are other approaches to define customization points, too):

```
Node::Node(std::string const& value)
    : value(my_convert<T>(value))
    , leftChild(nullptr)
    , rightChild(nullptr) {
}
```

This approach assumes that there is a primary template defined which probably defines a suitable default, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
T my_convert(std::string const& value) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(value);
}
```

It could be customized for a specific target type using template specialization:

```
template <>
int my_convert<int>(std::string const& value) {
    return std::stoi(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would make your constructor and other members take T, do you have a reason not to?

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
 T value;
Node * left, * right;

 Node(T const & value)
  : value(value), left(), right()
 { }
 ...
};
```

Comment: I always take value from string, which means I always call constructor of Node with string as a type of argument. I tried like this before but then there is a problem with not matching constructor and probably I would need to provide some auto mechanism,  so when Node is type of int the compiler will treat string „2” as int or something like that